# Magento 2 - How to create Megamenu for mobile?

Tags: magento2, megamenu

I have a desktop megamenu with alias **menu-top** & I have created megamenu for mobile with alias **menu-top-mobile** but it's not reflecting. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you gave us little information about the question

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any theme? If you're, then there might be an option to configure it for mobile screens. I've to look at how you've structured your theme for the Magento store.

On the other side, if you want to use you can go for Ultimo, Porto and SM Market they do provide responsive layout and mega-menu feature.

I hope that will work for you.